# Calling WMIC.EXE from Java (hangs)

Tags: java, windows, subprocess

I am trying to call WMIC.EXE from Java to acquire battery information.

Here is the source in JavaX (an extended Java dialect): http://tinybrain.de/1001824

To see the equivalent Java source, look [here](http://tinybrain.de:8080/tb-int/get-transpiled.php?id=1001824&raw=1) (just the first 60 lines are important, really).

You can run this program with [x30.jar](http://tinybrain.de/x30.jar) - or by just compiling and running the [Java source](http://tinybrain.de:8080/tb-int/get-transpiled.php?id=1001824&raw=1).

Basically it just produces a process (via a .bat file) and gets its output. The "backtick" function works fine with everything else, including stuff on Windows. Just not with WMIC - everything hangs.

The command run is this:

```
WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining /Format:List
```

Running this in the command prompt works fine... just not in Java. Java is weird with subprocesses, really.

Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/13367685/3196753.

Quoting:

> You will need to get and close your `OutputStream` before getting and using your `InputStream`.  That will confirm to the process that you've started that you have finished sending input (in this case, no input) to the process.
>
> ```
> p.getOutputStream().close();
> ```
>
> Remember that on the `Process` object, `getInputStream()` input comes from the output stream of the process, and `getOutputStream()` output goes to the input stream of the process.